# Application display virtualization

Tags: virtualization

I'm looking for a technology that supports remoting the display of individual applications hosted on a Windows server.  As far as I can tell most virtualization solutions (from VMWare, Citrix, etc.) only support remote display of the entire desktop (i.e., session virtualization). Are there any solutions out there for this configuration ?  I want to be able to host multiple instances of a Windows application on the server and allow multiple users to simultaneously access the display of their specific instance without the overhead of running multiple virtualized OSs.

Answer (score 1):

Application display virtualization is a broad term describing software that can make portability, compatibility and manageability of applications, allowing multiple applications to run on the same system. Essentially a virtualized application is not installed, but it executes just as if it was. Many virtualized display applications work only for the entire desktop. This can be useful in many cases. However, there are certain situations where you as a system operator may only want to allow outside users to access certain applications.
If your goal is to host multiple instances of a Windows application on the server and allow multiple users to simultaneously access the display of their specific instance without the overhead of running multiple virtualized OSs, there are some options available to you. One of the simplest is creating a server cluster.

When you want to run multiple instances of the same application by
running the same code or different codes that work together to provide a single service, a cluster is ideal. In either case each client only sees one section of the application. You can choose to either clone or partition the application and create multiple instances.
There are programs that will automate this for you. Examples are SAM (Server and Application Monitor) by Solarwinds and Dell Server Monitoring. These solutions tend to be pricey, but for a large firm that needs to have the ability to create these instances on the fly, this can be a great benefit.

Dell: http://www1.euro.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/sitelets/solutions/management/server_monitor?c=eu&l=en

SAM : http://www.solarwinds.com/server-application-monitor.aspx